# Python counter only presenting individual letters and not words

Tags: python, count, cpu-word

I am using the python word counter to visualise word frequencies in a text file. However, I am trying to present the frequency of words and not letters.

Currently my code is informing me that 'e', 't' and 'a' are my most frequent words. How do I remedy this? Many thanks.

The code I have been using is

```
from collections import Counter
```

`word_counts = Counter(pitchforkr)`
`top_four = word_counts.most_common(4)`
`print(top_four)`

Thank you!

Comment: If  `pitchforkr` is a string, you might want to split on spaces before passing it to Counter.

Answer (score 0):

You should split your input string `pitchforkr` in a list of words before passing it to Counter. Do

`wc = Counter(pitchforkr.split())`

and then

`top_four = wc.most_common(4)`